# Angular: create is deprecated: use new Observable() instead

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I recently updated my version of angular using `ng update` 
and when running `ng lint`

I am getting the error `create is deprecated: use new Observable() instead`

```
this.data$ = Observable.create(t => {
    t.next(this.model);
    t.complete();
});
```

What is the syntax for new observable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In 2021 it is changed.

```
new Observable((observer: Observer<object>) => {
    observer.next(data);
});
```

instead of

```
new Observable((observer: Observer) => {
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
});
```

Answer (score 85):

Pretty simple

```
this.data$ = new Observable((observer: Observer) => {
  observer.next();
  observer.complete();
});
```

### Updated answer

```
this.data$ = new Observable<void>((observer) => {
  observer.next();
  observer.complete();
});
```

Instead of `void` you can put any type your observable is supposed to emit. Observer's `next` value type will be inferred for the callback.

Comment: You also should be able to use `of()`

Comment: @OneLunchMan it's not the same. If you use `of()` it just emits values. However, `of()` is not as capable as creating an Observable. There you can place a complicated logic

Comment: Gotcha, so the difference between needing more complex logic and not-

Comment: @OneLunchMan Not that simple :). When you are using `of` you are producing `.next` with values, however if you create an observable you can react on events and then pass some data to the subscribers as well as you could count these subscribers etc.

Comment: If "Observer" gives you a TS2314 Generic type 'Observer' error, try replacing it with "any" or "Observer<any>".

Answer (score 10):

Or you can use just

```
this.data$ = of(this.model);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
observableSubscription: Subscription;
```

**Creating Custom Observable**

```
const observer = new Observable((observer: Observer) => {
   observer.next();
   observer.error();
   observer.complete();
});
```

**Subscribing To Custom Observable**

```
this.observableSubscription = observer.subscribe((data:any) => {
   console.log(data);
})
```

**Unsubscribing**

```
this.observableSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I am sorry, do i understand correctly ? Observable is an object we observe. Observe or sometimes called subscriber is something that overlook our observable and react to it's next/error/complete states. If yes, why would u then make a const variable with a name observer that new Observable returns. It kinda mess logic up.

Answer (score 2):

on NgOnInt create custom observable like this

```
ngOnInit() {

const customObservable = new Observable((observer: Observer<object>){
  observer.next(this.modal);
  observer.complete();
})
```

subscribe it

```
this.customSubscription = customObservable.subscribe((data) => {

  // logic goes here 
})

}
```

later on, in ngOnDestroy unsubscribe it

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.customSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```