# Missing object properties in an observable return type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I had this method:

```
public progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack): Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> {
  return Observable.create((progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
    this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, progressTask$);
    return { unsubscribe() { } };
  });
}
```

which was compiling and working fine, only its `Observable.create()` method call was warned as being deprecated.

I thus tried to replaced the `Observable.create()` method call by an `of()` method call as in:

```
public progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack): Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> {
  return of((progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
    this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, progressTask$);
    return { unsubscribe() { } };
  });
}
```

But it gives me the compile error:

```
Type 'Observable<(progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => { unsubscribe(): void; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>'.
  Type '(progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => { unsubscribe(): void; }' 
is missing the following properties from type 'ProgressTask<Uint8Array>': body, loaded, total, taskIsCompletets(2322)
```

I also tried with each of these alternatives:

```
public progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack): Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> {
  return of((progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
    this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, progressTask$);
    return progressTask$.asObservable();
    // return of({body: '', loaded: 0, total: 0, taskIsComplete: false});
    // return new ProgressTask<Uint8Array>((soundtrack.getNbNotes(), 0);
    // return of(this.downloadService.createProgressTask<Uint8Array>(soundtrack.getNbNotes(), 0, new Array()));
    // return this.downloadService.createProgressTask<Uint8Array>(soundtrack.getNbNotes(), 0, new Array());
  });
}
```

But I still get the same compile error.

The service method signature:

```
public createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack, progressTask$?: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>): Uint8Array {
}
```

The progress task method:

```
public createProgressTask<T>(total: number, loaded: number, body?: T): ProgressTask<T> {
  if (body) {
    return new ProgressTask<T>(total, loaded, body);
  } else {
    return new ProgressTask<T>(total, loaded);
  }
}
```

The progress class:

```
export class ProgressTask<T> {

  body: T | undefined;
  loaded: number;
  total: number;

  constructor(total: number, loaded: number, body?: T) {
    this.loaded = loaded;
    this.total = total;
    if (body) {
      this.body = body;
    }
  }

  public taskIsComplete(): boolean {
    return this.total > 0 && this.total === this.loaded;
  }

}
```

The `rxjs` dependency:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~/dev/js/projects/angular/musicng$ npm ls rxjs
musicng@0.0.1 /home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/musicng
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.2
│ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/architect@0.1100.2
│ │ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
│ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.1100.2
│ │ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
│ ├─┬ @angular-devkit/core@11.0.2
│ │ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
│ ├─┬ inquirer@7.3.3
│ │ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @angular/cli@11.0.2
│ └─┬ @angular-devkit/schematics@11.0.2
│   └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @angular/common@11.0.2
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @angular/core@11.0.2
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @angular/forms@11.0.2
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @angular/router@11.0.2
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @ngx-translate/core@13.0.0
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @ngx-translate/http-loader@6.0.0
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @stephaneeybert/lib-core@0.1.58
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @stephaneeybert/lib-i18n@0.0.5
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @stephaneeybert/lib-pwa@0.1.34
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ @stephaneeybert/lib-toast@0.0.4
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ angular-ide@0.9.75
│ └── rxjs@5.0.1
├─┬ angular-in-memory-web-api@0.11.0
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
├─┬ codelyzer@6.0.1
│ ├─┬ @angular/core@9.0.0
│ │ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
│ └── rxjs@6.6.3 deduped
└── rxjs@6.6.3
```

UPDATE: I could work around the issue with the following:

```
public progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi$(soundtrack: Soundtrack): Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> {
  return new Observable((observer$ : Subscriber<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
    this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, observer$);
    return { unsubscribe() { } };
  });
}

public createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack, progressTask$?: Subscriber<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>): Uint8Array {
}
```

Comment: You should see a message with your deprecation warning that says: `use new Observable() instead`. So do that.

Comment: Yes I had seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55539103/958373 and tried that `return new Observable((progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
      this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, progressTask$);
      return { unsubscribe() { } };
    });` but it gave the error `Argument of type '(progressTask$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>, subscriber: Subscriber<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => TeardownLogic'.`